# determine size of the ram in R

Tags: r, memory, parallel-processing, partitioning

Is there any way to report the total amount of available system RAM from within R? I need an option that will work on any system, not just Windows.

Based on the amount of RAM available I want to partition my data and run the job in a parallel-serial way. If the RAM size is big enough I would use more cores and if the size is small I would use fewer cores with more partitions.

Comment: What do you mean by "the total size of the RAM in R software"? Do you mean the amount of free memory on the system you're running R on? Or do you mean how much memory R is currently using?

Comment: If you type in `help.search("memory")`, you get a list of things that contain the string in the function name or description. Included in that list is `memory.limit()`.

Comment: The total memory of the system, isn't it clear from my question? @divibisan

Comment: @Farhad It isn't, which is why the 2 answers you got answered different questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `benchmarkme` package has a function for this:

```
benchmarkme::get_ram()
#17.2 GB
```

Comment: Thank you that is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the garbage collection function : `gc()`

Comment: gc is confusing. It does not tell how much RAM the system has.